# New Partner Console: Update Sec Review documents for new version

Tags: appexchange, isv, security-review, partner-portal

I recently published a brand new Managed Package to the AppExchange. I passed Security Review as well. Now a few weeks later, I made some enhancements to my app, which also changed the documents that were required for the initial manual Security Review:

- Additions to some Solution Design chapters
- New Use Cases in the User Guide
- New Checkmarx Scan results
- and new False Positives

When I select the new package version for my Listing, it is auto-approved without going through the wizard again. I have no chance to provide the updated versions of the documents.

**Is this how it's supposed to be? Wasn't this different in the old process?**

Comment: I've checked internally and got to know that if the partner app has passed the review then the new version will be auto-approved so they do not need to do anything in the new UI. In the Old UI partner has to start review and complete all the steps but in the new this process is changed. Thanks

Comment: As you are from within your answer is especially trustworthy. Would you mind making your comment a real answer giving some links and quotes of original documents.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no document at the moment to quote but I can post it as an answer still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I've checked internally with the security review team and have inputs that if the partner app has passed the review then the new version will be auto-approved so they do not need to do anything in the new UI. In the Old UI partner has to start review and complete all the steps but in the new this process is changed.

There is no documentation at the moment quoting this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe this is expected behavior. In the old process if you had already gone through a full, manual security review then upon cutting a new version you would have to do a perfunctory review by clicking through the wizard and then the new version would be instantly approved. The new process seems to streamline things by just immediately approving new versions without the need to go through the wizard again. I think it's still a good idea to keep all your documents up to date as things change though because you will be tapped for a manual re-review eventually.